# Word for trying to appear noble

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word to describe someone who acts like they are very honorable and have very noble intentions, when it's really not the case?

E.g. "*Yeah I happened to see his wallet on the floor and wanted to return it to him as soon as I got it*

**Note(his intention was to steal it but he was unable to as he was caught and tries to cover it up)**

Comment: There are numerous words that might apply. See: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hypocrite

Answer (score 1):

You might try [***disingenuous***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous)

Defined by Merriam Webster as:

> lacking in candor;
>
> also: giving a false appearance of simple frankness: *calculating*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

- He's a fake (or, better, "he's faking it")
- He's a scammer
- She's bogus (adjective i.e. not "a bogus)
- She's a fraud
- He's a sham
- She's a pretender

You have quite a lot of choices for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[Tartuffe](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/Tartuffe)* (also lower case)

> A religious hypocrite, or a hypocritical pretender to excellence of any kind.

Similarly, *[Pharisee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/Pharisee)*

> A self-righteous person; a hypocrite.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*